# HTML/CSS: Why is my text not vertically aligning?

Tags: html, css

I feel crazy. Here is a [JsFiddle with a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/) to how to vertically center some text. It's from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css).

But even when I copy and paste the HTML and CSS into my local files, I cannot replicate. Here is my code:

This is my HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;      
}
```

This doesn't work. [image: Here is a screenshot]. What in the world is going on?

Comment: you've got to use display:table; on parent and display: table-cell; on child, otherwise it wont work, some kind of bug css

Comment: It works fine as it is for me, in IE11.  I see it centered.

Comment: I see it fine in Chrome, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify your DOCTYPE.  If you add this to the top of your HTML file, it will work.  This will cause your page to be HTML5 instead of, I believe, transitional.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Fool around with the DTD section in Fiddle Options on the left, and you can reproduce the non-centred version.